# Getting this result, how do I fix number 6? > [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6]]

Tags: python, list

I'm doing this exercise that requires me to concatenate 2 already sorted lists, and I'm not sure why the output is this way.
Also, I'm used to C so I'm usually writing lots of "useless" code when I could've done it simply with a python method. Do you think if I just keep solving exercises it'll come as natural for me to think in a pythonic way? If there's an easier way to solving this let me know.

My code:

```
    def conc_sorted(list1, list2):
    result = []
    i = 0
    while True:
        if not list1:             # checking if both lists still have anything in it
            result.append(list2)  # to avoid 'out of range'
            break
        elif not list2:
            result.append(list1)
            break
        else:           
            result.append(compare(list1, list2)) # calls compare() and appends whatever it pops     

    print result

def compare(list1, list2):
    if (list1[0] < list2[0]):       
        return list1.pop(0)
    else:   
        return list2.pop(0)
# exemple    
list1 = [1, 4, 6]
list2 = [2, 3, 5]
conc_sorted(list1, list2)
```

Output > [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6]]

Comment: What's your desired output? What about `list1.extend(list2).sort()`

Comment: Do you need to do this the long way or is this simply because of your C background? There are very simple Python ways around this, but maybe for the sake of the exercise, those methods are forbidden.

Comment: @albert nearly. `.extend` works inplace. Separate that across 2 lines.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: As you already did in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45424308/3991125) :) Thought that inplace operation is totally fine here...

Comment: @albert it's not OK, because `.extend` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @NathanSmith It's probably just C background. Here's the exercise:
"Write a function that merges two sorted lists into a new sorted list... You can do this quicker than concatenating them followed by a sort."

Comment: If the lists are already sorted, then you basically want the `merge` operation from `merge_sort`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's a nice method, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base case is appending single element lists to your result. You'll need to change `.append` to `.extend`:

```
if not list1:             
    result.extend(list2) 
    break
elif not list2:
    result.extend(list1)
    break
```

Comment: Why not concatenate and sort? Because that's O(nlogn) but you can do it in O(n) *if the lists are already sorted*. Think merge-sort. It's the merge part.

Comment: I didn't know about .extend and .sort
Any tips on a good way to learn methods? It's not that I don't know how to use it, it's that I don't know they existed. I'm used to having to code everything by hand like in C.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I didn't see the part that they were already sorted. My bad.

Comment: @Tax A good place to start would be the documentation (on SO as well as the python docs). Also, if this answer helped, do consider marking it accepted!

Answer (score 0):

You should use *extend* operation here instead of *append* because *append* only take single input(entity) at a time.
And yeah! I got a more simple code for your problem.
`x=[1,4,6]`

`y=[2,3,5]`

`z=x+y`

`z.sort()`

`print z`

Answer (score -1):

```
sorted (list1 + list2)
```

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]